# SwiftUI with Core Data: Fetch request with predicate crashes

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have successfully added Core Data to my SwiftUI project. I need to filter the results by type. When I add a predicate to the fetch request the app crashes at the point where the view containing the fetch request tries to load.

The error is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

```
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),
    sortDescriptors:[
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.type, ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.totalScore, ascending: false),
    ],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", Int16(1))) //this is the line that crashes the app
 var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
```

If I change the Int16(1) to Int16(0), the app does not crash but no data appears in the list.

This is the first app I have witten using core data so I need help.

Comment: I suspect your problem is your predicate format. %@ expects a `String` or a value that Swift can implicitly convert to a `String`, so what placeholder would you use for an `Int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to andrewbuilder.  He got me looking in the right direction.  The correct way to use a predicate that expects an Int is:

```
predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %i", Int16(1)))
```

I was using %@ when I should have used %i.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the int an NSNumber object:

```
NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", @(1))
```